# Cannot find module './assets/photo.jpg' error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import

I am getting a error like this  Cannot find module './assets/photo.jpg'. This the code in app.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import Intro from './components/Introduction'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="outerwrapper">
      <div className="wrapper2">
     <Intro content={{ image : "./assets/photo.jpg",
     name : "Hello",
     text : "An undergraduate electrical and electronic engineering student"

    }} />      
 </div>

</div>
```

Code in Introduction.js component. I can import the image by entering the location of the image into require function. Also the image won't load without the require function.

```
import React from 'react';


function Intro(props) {
    return (

       <div className="Intro">
           <img src={require(props.content.image)}/>
    <h1>{props.content.name}</h1>
    <p>{props.content.text}</p>
    </div>

)
}
export default Intro;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try import image as component (correct way,  require image - bad practice)

**App.js**

```
import Photo from './assets/photo.jpg'
...
<Intro content={{ 
   image : Photo, // pass Photo as prop
   name : "Hello",
   text : "An undergraduate electrical and electronic engineering student"
}} />
```

**Intro.js**

```
...
<img src={props.content.image}/>
```

Comment: What about rendering dynamically photos ? ( inside a map for example )

Comment: @infodev, If the image comes from a backend, it will be an external link to the image (example: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png - logo of Google). So Intro.js file, code: <img src={{uri: props.content.image}}/>

Comment: And if the image doesn't come from the backend?

Comment: if the image does not come from the backend then you can handle the error using the onEror method (set default picture using import picture from above)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the require and keep the path '/assets/photo.jpg' react will redirect automatically to the public folder. 
Make sure assets is under public.